# Cannot syncdb “DatabaseError: no such table: django_site”

Tags: python, django, git, virtualenvwrapper

I've already asked this question once but didn't get an answer, I've read every single example of this error occurring i can find on the Internet so I'm going to try here again with more information.

**What I am attempting:**
The cloning of a remote repo that I will then run live on my dev machine for development purposes.

**The problem I am having:**
After cloning my repo off the webserver, using pip requirements.txt to install dependencies into my virtualenv i attempt to syncdb to build the db and allow me to run the server with runserver but when I attempt to do this i get the error "DatabaseError: no such table: django_site" output.

**What I've tried:** Commenting out django-contrib-sites from my installed_apps. Manually installing django_sites using pip with and without --ignore-installed, pip says that "Successfully installed django-sites django" but still get the error. I have tried to "migrate" and "migrate --all" but I get the same error. I have also verified that the db db.sqlite3 is the db specified in the settings.py and is in the correct location.

**installed_apps** -

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'south',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'django.contrib.markup',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',

)
```

A number of these are homebrewed applications from the previous dev.

**Lines in .bashrc**

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/projects
source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper
```

The last line is because I am using Ubuntu on this dev machine, not 100% sure about that but I don't get any errors when starting bash.

**Deploy Folder**
Not sure what this is, it has my requirements.txt and some other files:
- httpd.conf 
- nowww.htaccess 
- plural.htaccess 
- requirements.txt
- ssl.htaccess
- wsgi.py

**Process I am using**

```
create virtualenv with mkvirtualenv envname

pip install django

git ssh clone from remote to local folder

pip install -r requirements.txt from repo

./manage.py syncdb
```

> DatabaseError: no such table: django_site

I really need to figure this out as it prevents me from deploying on my dev server at home and doing remote work. If anyone can help please do, i promise to detail an answer and even build a tutorial page somewhere if it turns out to be a complex solution.

Comment: move all the django related installed apps to the top, and then try to run syncdb

Comment: @karthikr Thanks for the effort but that didn't help either. Still getting “DatabaseError: no such table: django_site”

Comment: please paste and link the output of `python manage.py syncdb --traceback --verbosity 2`

Comment: @tuxcanfly traceback located @ http://pastebin.com/6Ehxt55h
Thanks for taking the time to reply to my thread, this is really important to me :)

Comment: Can you try these things: 1) put the `django.contrib.*` apps in the beginning of your installed apps list. Then syncdb OR 2) first disable all local applications by commenting them out (so only keep the `django.contrib.*` ones, then syncdb, then add the other apps, syncdb.

Comment: And also, which project are you trying to install?

Comment: @private Spectacular! It worked, at least I am on to a new more specific error. Thank you so much to those that helped. Once I work my way through these new errors I will take the time to author an article somewhere detailing the problem and your apparent solution. Once again, thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got affected by this issue.

@tuxcanfly what you're saying is true, but for some reason the `Site.objects.get_current().name` expression gets evaluated even though the `BLOG_NAME` is set in the `settings.py`.

I've posted a ticket (and a patch) to GitHub for this issue:
https://github.com/pigmonkey/django-vellum/issues/3

Using a `try/catch` rather than `gettattr` fixes it:
https://github.com/AndreMiras/django-vellum/commit/9c242e16dc62c218e075554c5f5c5bc590df8265

Comment: Works great, my home dev machine is thankful for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing south from your installed apps.  Then syncdb, add south back in and migrate --all

I went round and round with this issue for ages before figuring this out

Comment: Thanks for the input but upon commenting out south and attempting syncdb I get the same error as before

Comment: I guess it's a different problem than the one I was having.  Worth a try though.

Answer (score 1):

On examining the traceback http://pastebin.com/6Ehxt55h, you'll notice:

```
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/odd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vellum/models.py", line 15, in <module>
    from vellum import settings
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/odd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vellum/settings.py", line 10, in <module>
    BLOG_NAME = getattr(settings, 'BLOG_NAME', Site.objects.get_current().name)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/odd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 26, in get_current
    current_site = self.get(pk=sid)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/odd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 143, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
```

As you can see, you're calling `Site.objects.get_current().name` in the `vellum.models` module, whose table might not yet be ready during `syncdb`. So:

- add the `BLOG_NAME` setting to your settings - this will prevent the call to `django_site`  table as `getattr` will succeed

or

- delay the call to `from vellum import settings` to where you really need it - inside a class or a method

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yep, you nailed it. Vellum is actually a home-spun blog the previous jedi-master-dev had created. Thank you so much for detailing how to get a traceback in this scenario, im a little ashamed I didn't think of simply asking django what the problem is. I'm going to write a tutorial for other dense people like me. Once again, thanks tuxcanfly.